# UITableView BackgroundView in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, null, transparent

How to convert following code into swift to make UITableView Background transparent.

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
```

in Objective-C we set backgroundView = nil but nil in swift work in different ways.?

Any solution? please.

Answer (score 2):

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Comment: UITableView doesn't have any other subviews that might make it non-transparent. Only it's background color and the background color of it's cells...

Comment: That is right, @Muhammad try the code:          `self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()`. You will see the blue of your superview. Or go to your Storyboard superview of your UITableView and change its color.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = .clear
    return cell
}
```